# Jasper Report Netbeans no imprime desde una aplicación

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

estoy haciendo pruebas con Jasper Reports, imposible que imprima desde una aplicación, si lo veo en el preview,
El error es el siguiente.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl cannot be cast to class java.util.Collection (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.Collection is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at Persistencia.Reporte.listado(Reporte.java:22)
    at Persistencia.FachadaBD.listado(FachadaBD.java:224)
    at Logica.Fachada.listado(Fachada.java:266)
    at GraficaNueva.Reportes.btnCuentasActionPerformed(Reportes.java:171)
    at GraficaNueva.Reportes.access$200(Reportes.java:30)
    at GraficaNueva.Reportes$3.actionPerformed(Reportes.java:82)
```

Capa Persistencia:

FachadaBD.java

```
   public JasperPrint listado(File camino) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, JRException, SQLException{
        Reporte reporte = new Reporte();
        return reporte.listado(camino);
    }
```

reporte.java

```
public class Reporte {
    JasperPrint listado(File camino) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, JRException, SQLException {
        JasperReport reporteD = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(camino); //Carga del Reporte
        Connection conectando = Conexion.getInstancia().conectar();
        return JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporteD, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource((Collection<?>) conectando)); //Imprime Reporte
    }
}
```

Capa Logica

Fachada.java

```
   public JasperPrint listado(File camino) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, JRException, SQLException {
        return FachadaBD.getInstancia().listado(camino);
    }
```

Grafica

Reportes.java

```
 private void btnDominiosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        File camino = new File("src\\Reporte\\reporteCuenta.jasper");
        try {
            JasperPrint imprimeReporte = Fachada.getInstancia().listado(camino);
            JasperViewer vistaReporte = new JasperViewer(imprimeReporte, false);
            vistaReporte.setVisible(true);
            vistaReporte.setTitle("Listado de Dominios");
            vistaReporte.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Reportes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Reportes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nunca he usado Jasper pero vaya... has visto lo que estás haciendo?? En esta línea: `Connection conectando = Conexion.getInstancia().conectar();` declaras conectando como tipo `Connection` y en la siguiente: `(Collection<?>) conectando` intentas hacer un inline cast de `Connection` a `Collection`. Repito que no tengo ni idea de jasper, pero aparte de que el propio error te está diciendo lo que acabo de poner yo en castellano, no tiene sentido ese casteo. Diría que te falta algún paso en medio. Imagino que en vez de pasarle la conexión deberás usar esa conexión para obtener los datos? :)

Comment: ¿Para que usas `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`? Parece que no lo necesitas.

Comment: Sabes, que la idea no era utilizar el JRBeanCollectionDataSource pero me obliga el Apache Netbeans. He mirado como usar Jasper, pero no funciona bien en las versiones nuevas de Netbeans. Agradezco, Cualquier idea.